# Why is there a libvirt-qemu user (showing on the login screen) and how to remove it?

Tags: debian, users, login, qemu, libvirt

I didn't create this user - I think it was added by installing the "Virtual Machine manager" (`virt-manager`) on Debian10/KDE.

`grep -E 'libvirt|qemu' /etc/passwd` returns `libvirt-qemu:x:6xxxx:1xx:Libvirt Qemu,,,:/var/lib/libvirt:/usr/sbin/nologin`

KDE's User Manager doesn't show the account but it's displayed on the login screen on the left of the actual user account. I don't have a file `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/libvirt-qemu` like described in a solution [to the 2017 question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897026/why-do-i-have-a-libvirt-qemu-account-in-lock-switch-account-options-in-ubuntu) and could not find a bug report if it's due to a bug in `accountsservice` (why does the bug occur / why hasn't it been fixed since?).

**Why is this user created and how to remove it but still be able to use virt-manager?** If the solution is to not remove the user but to hide it by creating the /users/libvirt-qemu file why isn't that done when the user is set up already? If the user is necessary I'd find it strange that iirc it was only added after installing virt-manager but not after installing and using `aqemu`.

Comment: System users like that are generally created so that daemons can run without root privs, or drop root privs as soon as possible.  IIRC, user `libvirt-qemu` is created by the `libvirt-daemon-system` package, not `virt-manager`.  It probably wasn't hidden by default because 1. every display manager has its own, different way of hiding users and 2. the package devs probably didn't think about it because they've done the the sane, secure thing on their systems and disabled the "show user list" anti-feature on their display manager (showing a user list harms security because it reveals usernames).

Comment: That's helpful. I guess in that case there should be some API or cross-DPM config file. (And it would still be a bug.) Where can one disable showing a user list in KDE? It only shows on the login screen (no other system-users are shown there) but not in the User Manager

Comment: My guess is that libvirt-qemu is a system account but with a specific UID not in the default system range ( < 500 or something like this): `grep LIBVIRT_QEMU_UID /var/lib/dpkg/info/libvirt*` .

Comment: Yes, the UID is over 60000 (see the 6xxxx in the prior grep output). It is set explicitly during postinstall: `/var/lib/dpkg/info/libvirt-daemon-system.postinst:LIBVIRT_QEMU_UID=[...]` So the UID should be within the default system range / < 500?

Comment: As cas wrote, "every display manager has its own, different way of hiding users", and the UID is part of it without a specific config file telling it's a system account. I'd rather add the AccountService config file rather than change the UID for the wrong reasons.

Comment: I had a quick look at the source for accountservice's [user-classify.c](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/accountsservice/tree/src/user-classify.c), and it excludes users with a basename of `false` or `nologin` as their shell.   So, I'd guess that your display/login manager isn't using accountsservice anyway.   Which dm are you using? lightdm?  sddm?  other? If you don't know, run `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager`

Comment: sddm, the default of KDE. I think it's using accountsservice and I'll file a bug here if you or A.B. don't https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/accountsservice/accountsservice/-/issues/new

Comment: according to `apt-cache show sddm`, the sddm package doesn't list `accountsservice` in a Depends:, Recommends: or even Suggests: line.  I don't think sddm uses it.   Same for `xdm`, `wdm`, and `lxdm`.   By way of contrast, `gdm3` depends on it (so uses it and requires it), and `lightdm` Suggests it (uses it if it's installed, but doesn't require it).

Comment: @cas accounts-daemon is running and is using that. If you're right that issue was posted to the wrong repository. Any idea what could have caused it, how to solve it or at which repo to post a bugreport?

Comment: since it's sddm displaying the user list, that's probably the package to file a bug report against.  **IF** one is needed.  As I said, I don't think it uses accountsservice (the fact that it's installed and running doesn't necessarily mean that sddm uses it at all), so check your facts first and find out what method (if any) sddm uses to exclude system users from the list.

Comment: Alright, so from [#816 there](https://github.com/sddm/sddm/issues/816) it seems like it's caused by the UID being too large, created an issue here: https://github.com/virt-manager/virt-manager/issues/293

Comment: The issue should have been created on Debian, which is the one doing the integration between unrelated components, and which chose the UID. libvirtd doesn't have to care about a login screen, nor a login screen has to care about each and every user installed not as it would expect. It's about harmonious integration with UID 64055 (no need to hide it, all debian installations default to 64055). Here is the likely bug fix having created this arguably bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=844339 . A guest migration in a cluster working fine is better than a gui minor issue.

Comment: According to that bug report it's fixed since 2016 but it appeared on my Debian10 (or 9) machine long after that.

Comment: The fixed but isn't a display bug. The fixed bug is a bug about a live VM migration on a cluster of hypervisors

Answer (score 1):

`grep LIBVIRT_QEMU_UID /var/lib/dpkg/info/libvirt*` shows that the UID is over 60000. This problem is likely caused by the UID being too large. Changing the UID upon installation seem to be a workaround that hides the user. Another workaround would be to create a config-file containing `SystemAccount=true` as described in the linked 2017 question:

```
printf "[User]\nSystemAccount=true\n" | sudo tee /var/lib/AccountsService/users/libvirt-qemu
sudo systemctl restart accounts-daemon.service
```

---

It seems to be due to a bug in accountsservice in some cases. I have created a bug report [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/accountsservice/accountsservice/-/issues/96) using info provided by users cas and A.B. who made some helpful comments above. It doesn't seem to be [a bug of libvirt-manager](https://github.com/virt-manager/virt-manager/issues/293). It could be a bug of the Debian configuration of the libvirt-manager package - [bug report here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=993047) and [here](https://gitlab.com/libvirt/libvirt/-/issues/361).