# Are init scripts not removed after uninstalling packages?

Tags: linux, debian, software-installation, kde, uninstall

I installed and later uninstalled `webmin` with Apper years ago.

Since I switched to Wayland on Debian11/KDE starting the computer from standby, sessions [are breaking](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/684498/233262) all the time (currently once every second day on average).

After pressing ctrl+alt+F2, logging the user out with `pkill -KILL -u {username}`, and pressing ctrl+alt+F(8 for example) to show to login screen it shortly shows this error on a black background: `Failed to start LSB: web-based administration interface for Unix systems`.

Researching this error on the Web, it appears to be related to Webmin.

I checked that it's not installed anymore with `sudo apt-get remove webmin` (it shows `Package 'webmin' is not installed, so not removed`).

Running `sudo systemctl status webmin` shows:

```
● webmin.service - LSB: web-based administration interface for Unix systems
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/webmin; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-01-08 23:56:28 CET; 1 day 15h ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 2061 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/webmin start (code=exited, status=127)
        CPU: 1ms

hostname systemd[1]: Starting LSB: web-based administration interface for Unix systems...
hostname systemd[1]: webmin.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
hostname systemd[1]: webmin.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
hostname systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: web-based administration interface for Unix systems.
```

Are <strike>systemd services</strike> init scripts like Webmin not removed after removing packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Debian Policy-compliant packages, yes, systemd services are supposed to be removed along with the package.

However, this isn’t a systemd service, it’s an init script. Since these live in `/etc`, they are only removed if the package is *purged*, not just removed:

```
sudo apt purge webmin
```

In addition to that, `webmin` might not be a Policy-compliant package ([it hasn’t been available in Debian for nearly 15 years](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/webmin)).

Comment: Where could one see all the nondefault init scripts like with this /a/624262/233262? Especially if there's no easy way to view and manage all of them in a GUI, why isn't the user prompted to also remove it when uninstalling a package (e.g. via -purge)? Furthermore, this command also returned `dpkg: warning: while removing webmin, directory '/usr/share/webmin/authentic-theme/unauthenticated/js' not empty so not removed` so I removed that directory (which has a small config file). Lastly, can there be security issues (or at least stability-affecting problems) with not removing such init scripts?

Comment: There is `rcconf` but it's not a GUI. One also doesn't know which init scripts are useful and which aren't (for example because the package got removed). What effects could the nonpurged files have had after the webmin package itself got removed?

Comment: I don’t know of any GUI to manage init scripts. In well-behaved packages, init scripts which are left behind are no-ops, unless another package installs files which match the script’s expectations. Since `webmin` isn’t necessarily a package whose behaviour is well-defined, I can’t say whether there are any security issues or other problems related to it.