# What causes plasmashell to crash after waking from standby (wallpaper set to default, no taskbar, ...) with a 2nd display and how to restart it?

Tags: debian, kde, display, wayland, plasma

Since I connected a new screen to my PC it sometimes happens that when I wake my PC from standby (with that other screen turned off before and after standby) plasma seems to have crashed:

- The wallpaper is the default one
- Sometimes the lockscreen is the default one but sometimes it keeps my lockscreen (when I enter my password at the lockscreen I had to click on the password field or it didn't enter it)
- The panel at the bottom disappeared and when I click the Meta/Windows key nothing happens
- When I move windows like the konsole window, the window becomes invisible until it's at the new place

In system monitor it shows that plasmashell is running (started by systemd) and that startplasma-waylandsession is running (started by systemd->sddm->sddm-helper->startplasma-wayland->kwin_wayland)

I'm using Wayland on Debian11/KDE.

This is probably related to Wayland and definitely related to the monitor/having connected a new monitor.

---

Sometimes I have to reboot when I haven't disconnected the HDMI to that new monitor before waking from standby (even `loginctl unlock-session {id}` didn't help), probably I need to disconnect the HDMI before going to standby or waking and only connect it afterwards so things aren't screwed up. I haven't configured it to be my primary display and the display settings in KDE are fine so I don't know why it has all these problems. Hopefully, this is already solved in Debian 12 with Wayland. Sometimes (maybe even always by now as I'd need to test this) turning on the display ends the session.

---

When I enter `journalctl -b` it once only shows very three entries for the day at the bottom like "systemd: Started konsole." and many for the previous day even though I had my computer running for quite a while (note there's also a [loss of bash history when using Wayland on Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/684498/why-are-sessions-breaking-all-the-time-when-starting-from-standby-on-debian-wayl) and I used to restore it from backups until this became too frequent. Wayland-KDE bugs really should get fixed) and one time it had many messages but nothing that looks like it could be related except for `kernel: pci 0000:02:00.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref] kernel: pci 0000:02:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]`. Also this last time, it had messages (including the above) with timestamps from after waking from standby, even `systemd[1]: Finished Suspend.` `systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.`
`systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.` have timestamps from when I waked the computer from standby, not when I put it into standby. Nevertheless, the last two messages with timestamps when/before I put it into standby are `systemd-sleep[...]: Suspending system...` `kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)`.

I usually try running `killall plasmashell` and `kstart5 plasmashell` but that doesn't work (for example the taskbar is still missing) so I need to end the session and log in again via `qdbus org.kde.Shutdown /Shutdown logout`. So far I couldn't find any way to restart it.

This is happening relatively often.

Another thing that's happening often but not as often is that my display resolution (in KDE) is set to the maximum of the other screen when waking from standby. The other screen is powered off even during the standby time.

I found this error in a console, it may be related:

```
qt.qpa.wayland: Ignoring unexpected wl_surface.leave received for output with id: {id} screen name: "HDMI-A-1" screen model: "HDMI-A-1-{id}" This is most likely a bug in the compositor.
```

Maybe this problem is fixed in the next version of **qtwayland5** (currently 5.15.2-3). Maybe it's the same as [this bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=420160#c16) which seems to fixed [here](https://invent.kde.org/qt/qt/qtwayland/-/merge_requests/27) (the bug was marked as duplicate).

Another thing that is happening sometimes is that plasmashell just randomly seems to crash without any error or doing anything (the taskbar simply disappears). Which logs to check to find out why this happened?

**Edit**: If I don't have another display connected with HDMI, it doesn't occur anymore (the four bullet points at the top), only the problem where the screenlocker is broken and I need to run `loginctl unlock-session {id}` still does (when waking from standby and after a while with screenlocker turned on) - I think I confused these two problems as one problem, but these are two separate issues. I need to check if it still occurs with the display connected.

---

[My bugreport about this](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=457996) has been closed because Debian still ships very outdated KDE software. I then created [a bug report for Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1018003).

If you don't know what may be causing this:

- how would you investigate further?
- what could be done to properly restart plasmashell (when the bottom panel doesn't show and the wallpaper is set to the default one) when restarting plasmashell doesn't work properly except for logging out (which closes all running apps)?